# npm install: node-waf not found. What to do?

Tags: node.js

Using node -v v0.10.29, npm -v 1.4.14 (http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu)

when doing a "npm install" of a project, "zlib@1.0.5 preinstall" always shouts "sh: 1: node-waf: not found"

I've seen some other questions about the same thing, but I still don't know what I have to do to make "npm install" work.

Thanks.

Comment: can you install node-gyp (used instead of node-waf): sudo npm install -g node-gyp

Comment: @alihaider: have node-gyp installed. However, that same error still shows up. And it is ubuntu (13.10)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `node-waf` package has been replaced by `node-gyp`, this is why you get the not found error. The package is not available anymore: https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=node-waf

The `zlib` package you want to install has not been updated for years. Node.js has built-in support for Zlib, see the manual for more details: [Zlib](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that `node-waf` was ever its own separate package like `node-gyp` currently is, but yeah, zlib support has been available in node core for quite awhile now.

Comment: @mscdex True, it was part of Node.js. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm not using zlib directly. Some other package must be dependent on it. Having node-gyp installed, I'm still confronted with the same issue: I can't do "npm install".

Comment: @tokosh What's the name of the package which has the dependency on zlib? Maybe it's a package that isn't maintained either. You might want to look for an alternative.

Comment: I had to update the version of node-rest-client to the latest. However, on a different machine with (almost, I don't know what is different) the same environment it worked without problems. I guess, your answer is the correct one. But for all ppl who come across this, this issue is pretty annoying and probably they will do something similar (update version, use different package) to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is there some sort of place where one can look up support like this?  I'm trying to install `archive` and it fails due to `node-waf` not being present, and I can't find any other packages that seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

node-zopfli does the exact same thing, if all you want is to gzip a stream.
https://github.com/duralog/node-zopfli

example I use for tar-gzipping stuff:

```
fstream.Reader({ 'path': filesFolder, 'type': 
   'Directory' }).
   pipe(tar.Pack()) 
    //.pipe(zlib.Gzip()) // this is what I used to do
    .pipe(zopfli.createGzip())
    .pipe(out); // out is an output stream, obviously
```